# text link hover fade out fade in div

Tags: javascript, text, hyperlink, hover, fade

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryjquery_fadein.htm

1) instead of button, change it to a text link.
2) instead of on click, change it to on hover.
3) i would like it to be like this:

text link 1
text link 2
text link 3

hover over text link 1, will fade in div 1

hover over text link 2, will fade out div 1, and fade in div 2.

hover over text link 3, will fade out div 2, and fade in div 3.

hover over any text link will fade out what ever the active div is, and fade in whatever text link you hover.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
<br><br>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code with text link 1,2,3? This code is the one you copied from w3schools website.

Comment: yes, thats what i want to change. i want to change to this:

1) instead of button, change it to a text link. 2) instead of on click, change it to on hover. 3) i would like it to be like this:

text link 1 text link 2 text link 3

hover over text link 1, will fade in div 1

hover over text link 2, will fade out div 1, and fade in div 2.

hover over text link 3, will fade out div 2, and fade in div 3.

hover over any text link will fade out what ever the active div is, and fade in whatever text link you hover.

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar to the the code posted, but you have to use the `.hover()` function then change the specific div like so.

http://jsfiddle.net/r3Dsd/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#link1").hover(function () {
        $("#div1").fadeIn();
        $("#div2").fadeOut();
        $("#div3").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#link2").hover(function () {
        $("#div2").fadeIn();
        $("#div1").fadeOut();
        $("#div3").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#link3").hover(function () {
        $("#div3").fadeIn();
        $("#div1").fadeOut();
        $("#div2").fadeOut();
    });
```

A better way of doing it would be to add an active class to the div based on the corresponding hover. Then use CSS3 transitions to fade them in and out

Comment: excellent. but it is showing all 3 boxes. how to show only 1 box at a time. the active box needs to fade out and then the other box fade in.

Comment: You could add `fadeOut()` on the other div you want to fadeOut. If it wasn't visible in the first place, then it should show up

Comment: @user2343800 I've updated the answer with it working as you want, but at the bottom I suggested a better way of going about this.

Comment: 1) ok i added 4th div orange. this orange div shows up first. 2) if hover link1, then red box fades in but over where orange box is, so that orange box does not show. 3) hover over link2, will fade in green box but on top. 4) all boxes are in the same positions, no jumping around. 

http://www.riversidelab.com/_08/back-fade05.html